# What problem on syntax error in Insert Into Statement

Tags: vb.net

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim objCon As New OleDbConnection
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strConnect As String = "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Abry\Documents\Bilik.accdb"
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Private Sub TempahButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TempahButton.Click
        Dim startDate As Date
        Dim str As String
        startDate = DateTimePicker1.Value

        objCon.ConnectionString = strConnect
        objCon.Open()
        str = "Insert into bilik(Bilik, Tujuan, Tarikh, Masa Masuk, Masa Keluar) values('" & BilikComboBox.SelectedIndex & "','" & TujuanTextBox.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString & "','" & MasaMasukMaskedTextBox.Text & "','" & MasaKeluarMaskedTextBox.Text & "')"

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, objCon)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Bilik", CType(BilikComboBox.SelectedIndex, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Tujuan", CType(TujuanTextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Tarikh", CType(DateTimePicker1.Value, Date)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Masa Masuk", CType(MasaMasukMaskedTextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Masa Keluar", CType(MasaKeluarMaskedTextBox.Text, String)))

        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            objCon.Close()
            TujuanTextBox.Clear()
            BilikComboBox.Text = ""
            DateTimePicker1.Value = ""
            MasaMasukMaskedTextBox.Clear()
            MasaKeluarMaskedTextBox.Clear()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)


        End Try


    End Sub
End Class
```

This database on MS ACCESS

Always error for Insert Into Statement

Comment: As it's using parameters (which is good), it should be `str = "Insert into bilik(Bilik, Tujuan, Tarikh, [Masa Masuk], [Masa Keluar]) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"`. Note that I used square brackets to quote the column names because they have spaces in the names (that would have been the syntax error).

Comment: Never use spaces when you assign a name to a Fields or a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Option Strict On should be set for this project and all projects. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Keep you database objects local so you can control that they are closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks will do this for you even if there is an error.

You are concatenating the values into your sql (very bad - opens your app to sql injection) and then trying to add parameters when none exist in the Insert statement. You can use the question mark as a placeholder for parameters or use names. Access doesn't care about the names; only that the position in the sql statement matches the order in which the parameter is added to the parameter's collection. I like to use names so I can easily check that I am adding the parameters in the correct order.

The .Text property contains a String so it is not necessary to convert it to a string.

The .Value property of a DataTimePicker is a DateTime. No need to convert.

When adding parameters use the overload that accepts the OleDbType and, ideally, the size. You will need to check the fields in your database to get this information.

Don't show message boxes or clear text boxes until the connection is closed. Connections are precious objects and should be opened at the last minute and closed as soon as possible.

```
Dim strConnect As String = "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Abry\Documents\Bilik.accdb"

Private Sub TempahButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TempahButton.Click
    Try
        Using objCon As New OleDbConnection(strConnect)
            Dim str = "Insert into bilik(Bilik, Tujuan, Tarikh, [Masa Masuk], [Masa Keluar]) values(@Bilik, @Tujuan, @Tarikh, @MasaMasuk, @MasaKeluar);"
            Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, objCon)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Bilik", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = BilikComboBox.SelectedIndex.ToString
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Tujuan", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TujuanTextBox.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Tarikh", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@MasaMasuk", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = MasaMasukMaskedTextBox.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@MasaKeluar", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = MasaKeluarMaskedTextBox.Text
                objCon.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using 'Closes and disposes the connection
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    TujuanTextBox.Clear()
    BilikComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1
    DateTimePicker1.Value = ""
    MasaMasukMaskedTextBox.Clear()
    MasaKeluarMaskedTextBox.Clear()
End Sub
```